# add button in footer tableview in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, button, tableview

I want to add a button in a table footer. I have written this code but the button does not work.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var footerView : UIView?
    footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50))
    footerView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    let dunamicButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    dunamicButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    dunamicButton.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    dunamicButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)
    dunamicButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTouched:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    footerView?.addSubview(dunamicButton)

    return footerView
}

func buttonTouched(sender:UIButton!){
println("diklik")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}
```

Thanks!

edit my class tableView

import UIKit

import GoogleMobileAds

class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SetingTableViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tabelView: UITableView!

 var data = ["BINATANG","BUAH","MAKANAN","SAYURAN","TUBUH","RUMAH","SEKOLAH","WARNA","ALAM","KENDARAAN","MAINAN"]



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabelView.rowHeight = 100.0

}
```

func SetingTableViewControllerDidCancel(controller : SetingTableViewController)

```
{

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

func SetingTableViewControllerDidDone(controller : SetingTableViewController){

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView,

    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return data.count

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView,

    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tabelView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

    as! KategoriCell



        cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: data1[indexPath.row]+"2")

        cell.labelCell.text = data[indexPath.row]



    return cell

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "playId"{

        let indexPath = tabelView.indexPathForSelectedRow()



        let item = data[indexPath!.row]



        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PlayViewController

        detailViewController.kategoriKe = indexPath!.row

        }

        else if segue.identifier == "settingId"{

            let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController

                as! UINavigationController

            let controller = navigationController.topViewController

                as! SetingTableViewController

             controller.delegate = self

        }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(indexPath.row, forKey: "kategoriIdx")
```

}

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    var height : CGFloat

    height = 50

    return height

}



 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    var footerView : UIView?

    footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50))

    footerView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()



    let dunamicButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton

    dunamicButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    dunamicButton.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    dunamicButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)

    dunamicButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTouched:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)



    footerView?.addSubview(dunamicButton)



    return footerView

}



func buttonTouched(sender:UIButton!){

    println("diklik")

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 50.0

}



func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController,

    willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController,

    animated: Bool) {

    if viewController === self {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(

    -1, forKey: "kategoriIdx")

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Any result came or not?

Comment: button not work....no respons.

Comment: Try this-     dunamicButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonTouched:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your code and it is working fine but if it is not working for you then there is one more way to do it go to your ViewController in storyBoard then add a new view blow your cell as shown below:

[image]

After that you can connect an action of that button with this code:

```
@IBAction func btn(sender: AnyObject) {

    println("Working")
}
```

Check [THIS](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Table-With-Footer-View) sample code.
This will work fine.

[HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Add-FoterView-Programetically) is Sample project with your code.

Comment: my button still not work...  my class tableview as follows:                                                               class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SetingTableViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tabelView: UITableView!

Comment: can you send me sample project?

Comment: @Dharmesh Kheni Thanks your code is working .. only problem is UIView is displaying on the Starting  when  i am trying to Load the  the Related UItableview

Comment: Can you share your demo project?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your function to action :

```
 @IBAction func buttonTouched(sender:UIButton!){
      println("Button was clicked", sender)
 }
```