# After scroll of UITableview push a view on the footer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have one tableview and i scrolled down,Array datas are appeared,if array have no data after the scroll want to come a view on the bottom of the view

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger totalRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];//first get total rows in that section by current indexPath.
    if(indexPath.row == totalRow -1){

        [self.tableViewMesages setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 65.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-115.0)];
        [self.footer setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-55, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,55.0)];
        self.imgvwSmily.alpha=1;
        [self.footer addSubview:self.imgvwSmily];

    }
    else
    {
        [self.tableViewMesages setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 65.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-65.0)];
        [self.footer setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,55.0)];
        self.imgvwSmily.alpha=0;
        [self.footer addSubview:self.imgvwSmily];

    }
}
```

i tried with this code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: You want to add a view that will be displayed under all data cell? You can use footer or another cell to achieve this.

Comment: @kelin Not like that after all data i want to show a view on the bottom of main view not in the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can add footer view. Your footer view will be visible when your
>   array don't have any data left to show and you reached to bottom of
>   uitableview.

Take a look how to add footer view in UITableview on below links

[UITableFooterview Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000279/ios-8-swift-how-to-add-footer-for-tableview-using-separate-datasource)

[UITableFooterview Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217656/add-button-in-footer-tableview-in-swift)

I hope this may helps to solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. 
my problem is  i have 10 data and i listed on tableview ,scrolled tableview after 10 data listed a view want to come from the bottom and said like no more data

Comment: @ManjuS : Yes exactly you just need to add footerview. Whether you have 10 records or 50 it doesn't matter. When tableview will reach to it's bottom you will able to see footer view. Just try to integrate from examples. Give background colour to your footer view.